# Breakpoint in dart library does not work

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I am experimenting with Dart and libraries and I cannot seem to get a breakpoint to work in my library class.

I've created a library in `lib/myLib/myLib.dart`, defined a class there and set a breakpoint in the constructor. I construct this class from my main method, defined in `web/test.dart`. Breakpoints which are set in the main method are hit, but the breakpoints from the library are not hit. I am certain the code executes though, as i can step into the library's code from the main method.

Is this a known issue, or do i need to configure something? I am using Dart Editor version 1.0.0_r30798 and DartSDK version 1.0.0.10_r30798 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably importing your own library like this:

```
import “package:mylib/lib.dart”;
```

If so, you should put your breakpoint in the files located under the “packages” folder in your project.

Alternatively, you can import your lib with a relative path:

```
import “../lib/lib.dart”;
```

Comment: Hmm, i had tried this both ways IIRC, and had set breakpoints in all packages folders as well, but now that i try it again this seems to work, but only if i import with the relative path.

Answer (score 2):

I have sometimes issues with breakpoints. Either they get ignored or the execution halts at the breakpoint but instead of the file with the code a new window with an error message is opened in the Editor('file not found' or similar).

In such cases I use the Dartium integrated debugger whihc never let me down.
<kbd>F12</kbd> in Dartium > Editor dialog > choose 'no' > Dartium developer tools tab sources > open source from 127.0.0.1:3030 node > set breakpoint > start reload/execution with <kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Bubblewrap, can you create a small test case demonstrating the issue, and file a bug at dartbug.com/new, w/ the test case attached?